# Django: Is it possible to create a model without an app?

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django, so i don't know if the answer is obvious. I created models.py inside a project and when i tried syncDB, it did not create the tables defined in models.py. Only when i create models.py inside an app and after registering the app with INSTALLED_APPS, the tables are getting created on syncDB.

Is this is how Django works? Or am i missing something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Django only syncs what's defined in `INSTALLED_APPS`. The name is pretty straight-forward. Django's going to look for at least a module (directory with an `__init__.py`) with a `models.py` file inside. So yes, you need an "app", but that app can be just a directory with just `__init__.py` and `models.py` files inside.

Comment: I wonder if it can be considered bad practice 

Answer (score 1):

from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb):

> syncdb Creates the database tables for all **apps in INSTALLED_APPS** whose tables have not already been created.

Answer (score 1):

Yup — I think models can only live in an app (pretty much everything in Django has to be an app).

The following section of the docs implies it, even if it doesn’t quite say it directly:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#using-models

And this section of the tutorial *sort of* explains apps:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models

Comment: Links are now broken (20 APR 2023)